# Writing to .csv

Tags: vb.net

I have written a basic console application and I want to write the data entered to a .csv file 
When I enter test data the execution of the module is fine but it does not write to the .csv

I am trying to create an automated test data generation and this is my first attempt at vb by writing to .csv.
I want the code to pop up an input screen where data is input and written to a.csv file , the pop up is fine but the .csv is blank 
Code. I have:

```
Module Module1
    Dim objFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\User\Documents\test.csv.csv", True)

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("what is your name")
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("What is your Age")
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("What is your Your Group")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: We are not mind readers, please update post with code you have tried and where you are having issue.

Comment: Module module 1

Comment: odule Module1
    Dim objFile As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\Users\User\Documents\test.csv.csv", True)

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Customer Name ")
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Demographic Group")
        Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("Postcode")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module

Comment: Console.WriteLine writes to the command line output. There's no code here which would save anything into a CSV (or any other) file. You can find examples of how to write to files very easily by googling

Comment: You are not storing input from user and you are not writing anything to file stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I believe you are looking for.  There are some pretty basic concepts that you appear to be missing (like storing values in variables and accessing those variables later).  This sample demonstrates how to perform the task you described, but isn't useful in any practical sense.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?")
        Dim Name As String = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("What is your age?")
        Dim Age As String = Console.ReadLine()

        Console.WriteLine("What is your group?")
        Dim Group As String = Console.ReadLine()

        Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\test\outputfile.csv")
            sw.WriteLine(Name & "," & Age & "," & Group)
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I agree , in my defence i started this 3 hours earlier with a teach yourself book in one hand and a demo version of visualstudio on my PC so still finding my way around the book and how it is structured. I really appreciate the responses ,from the forum